# How to disable hierarchical dotted lines in SWT Tree on Windows?

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am trying to hide hierarchical dotted lines for SWT Tree view.

[image: SWT Tree with hierarchical dotted lines on Windows]

How do I hide these dotted lines? Is there any special options?
What is the best and correct way to do it?

I found that with TableTree it is possible to do that - in this example:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesTableTreeTableTree.htm

I would use TableTree - but it's deprecated now.

**UPDATE**

Found that I can use `SWT.FULL_SELECTION` option and the lines now hidden.

[image: SWT Tree with disabled dotted lines using SWT.FULL_SELECTION]

Now the question is what does this option mean and why we getting hidden lines - will it work for all Windows versions?

**References**

http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t66912.html thanks to @default locale
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25071

Comment: There are several hacks on eclipse zone. http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t66912.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SWT.FULL_SELECTION should be used when creating the Tree. The result of it is exactly what's needed - there is no hierarchical dotted lines in full selection mode.